# Define a Function inside an Object with a variable as part of the function

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to define a function inside an object where one item the portion of the function to be processed is based on a variable.  In the code below, how do I get `*dynamicValue*` to be saved as the current value of `myColumn`?

```
  var viewColumns = [0];
  var count = 0;
  var dataCount = 3;
  var total = 0;
  while (count < dataCount) {
    var myColumn = count + 1;
    var viewColumnDescription = {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return dt.getValue(row, *dynamicValue*);
        },
        type: "number",
        role: "annotation"
      };
    viewColumns.push(myColumn);
    viewColumns.push(viewColumnDescription);
    count += 1;
  }
```

Note that I have hard coded a value for dataCount so that all variables are defined in the sample section but in my actual code this value currently changes to be a number between 1 to 3.  It could be more at a later date as well so I want to be able to use a loop to define the items.

In this case the resulting object should be as if I did this:

```
viewColumns = [0,
      1, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return dt.getValue(row, 1);
        },
        type: "number",
        role: "annotation"
      },
      2, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return dt.getValue(row, 2);
        },
        type: "number",
        role: "annotation"
      },
      3, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return dt.getValue(row, 3);
        },
        type: "number",
        role: "annotation"
      },
      {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return 0;
        },
        label: "Total",
        type: "number",
      },
      {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return 'Total: ' + (dt.getValue(row, 1) 
                           + dt.getValue(row, 2) 
                           + dt.getValue(row, 3));
        },
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
      }
    ];
```

If `dataCount` were 2 instead of 3, all references to `dt.getValue(row, 3)` would be removed. Hopefully once I know the first part I can figure out how to have the last function calculate the total of all available rows.

This is to be used to create charts using the Google Visualization API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `myColumn` and `viewColumnDescription` from `var` into `let`.
Replace `*dynamicValue*` with `myColumn`

Or if you don't want to use `let`, you'll have to use closures to make sure that the value of myColumn is stored in the appropriate scope...

If you don't use let - or you don't put it in a closure, all of the `viewColumnDescription` functions would see `myColumn` with value = 3

Sample with `let` - note that I've used it only where strictly necessary.

```
  var viewColumns = [0];
  var count = 0;
  var dataCount = 3;
  var total = 0;
  while (count < dataCount) {
    let myColumn = count + 1;
    let viewColumnDescription = {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return dt.getValue(row, myColumn);
        },
        type: "number",
        role: "annotation"
      };
    viewColumns.push(myColumn);
    viewColumns.push(viewColumnDescription);
    count += 1;
  }
```

Comment: SWEET!  Thank you!!  I was not aware of let vs var so I did a quick search to further educate myself.

Comment: It's probably the trickiest thing to understand with JavaScript, but it will save you a lot of headaches once you get it right :)